# subtotaling on live data macro

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have created a data table through Sharperlight reporting thats generates its results into excel as shown below:-

[image]

What I want to do is develop a macro that will subtotal all categories for the data.  There is no determined length size of the table other than it will always be columns G - J.

This way my hope is when a user refreshes the table using the menu on the side they will then be able to run a macro to get a quick one line total for each category.

Can anyone help with this???

Comment: how do users change the values in the menu? typing?

Comment: they double click to open sub menus for year, month and posting type.  All this does is refresh the table and allow them to filter on certain specifics like year.

Comment: what event is runs the refresh? cause you could simply add another sub after the refresh to calculate totals

Comment: when the table refreshes it pulls from a SQL query. Without having to copy and paste values only I cannot see a way to subtotal the groups?

Comment: what row does the data start

Comment: headers are row 4, data row 5 always columns G - J

Comment: a Pivot table (and the filter possibilities it offers by default) is not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the sheet1 tab > View Code
[image: sheet1 view code]

paste this code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 Then
        If Target.Row = 4 Or Target.Row = 5 Or Target.Row = 6 Then Totals
    End If
End Sub
```

then add a `module` right click `Sheet1` in the `Project Explorer` in the `VBE window` and `Insert > Module`

 then pate this code

```
Sub Totals()

    Range("C10:D" & Range("C10:C" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row).ClearContents
    Dim startAtRow As Long
    startAtRow = 10 ' Set starting row
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    lr = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arr(lr - 4) As String
    For i = 5 To lr
        arr(i - 5) = Range("J" & i).Value
    Next i
    Dim arr2() As String
    arr2 = arr
    RemoveDuplicate arr
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) - 1
        Range("C" & (i + startAtRow)).Value = arr(i)
        For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2) - 1
            If arr(i) = arr2(j) Then
                Range("D" & (i + startAtRow)).Value = Range("D" & i + startAtRow).Value + Range("I" & (j + 5)).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub RemoveDuplicate(ByRef StringArray() As String)
    Dim lowBound$, UpBound&, A&, B&, cur&, tempArray() As String
    If (Not StringArray) = True Then Exit Sub
    lowBound = LBound(StringArray): UpBound = UBound(StringArray)
    ReDim tempArray(lowBound To UpBound)
    cur = lowBound: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(lowBound)
    For A = lowBound + 1 To UpBound
        For B = lowBound To cur
            If LenB(tempArray(B)) = LenB(StringArray(A)) Then
                If InStrB(1, StringArray(A), tempArray(B), vbBinaryCompare) = 1 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next B
        If B > cur Then cur = B: tempArray(cur) = StringArray(A)
    Next A
    ReDim Preserve tempArray(lowBound To cur): StringArray = tempArray
End Sub
```

Now every time user is changing the values of D4,D5,D6 your results should update. The categories will be displayed starting at C10 down, and the totals at D10 down. Looks like this ( sample version )

[image: results]

Comment: That's fantastic!!  Many thanks.  if I wanted the subtotals to appear on a seperate sheet instead of C10 and D10 down is it easy enough to change?

Comment: yes. prefix the `Range("D" ...` with `Sheets("sheet name").Range("D" ...  + sheets(1).Range("I" ...` and if you want to change the starting row then refer to the comment in the code where it says `Set starting row` and row change value from `10` to what you want. Also if you want to change the column then either use `Sheets("sheet name").Cells(startAtRow, [column number here])...` or replace letters `C` and `D` with for example `A` and `B`